# How to convert a string to soap message in php and send it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, soap

I have this html code-

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function diffid(){
if     (document.getElementById('diff').checked) {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <form action="soap_msg.php" id='pass_reset' method='post'>
    <input id='same_id' type='radio' name='choice' value='exixting' 
onclick="javascript:diffid();">
    Use logged in user id? <br>
    <h6>OR</h6>
    <input id='diff' type='radio' name='choice' value='diff_id' 
onclick="javascript:diffid();">
    Enter different UserID <br/><br>
    <div id="show" style="display:none">
    UserID<br>
    <input name='diff_id' type="text"><br><br>
  </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  <input type="reset">
  </form>

</body>
```

which is a simple form as shown in the attatchment.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP4zc.png)
 When a submit button is pressed, a php file is triggered.

In this php file, I want to send the **username** to the web service after enclosing it in a soap message and also **receive** the response from the web service(also a soap message).

How to implement this? I am a beginner in web services and very confused.
Please help me.

I want to do everything in php file only. But if there is any other easier way to do this whole stuff please suggest.